# Decode base64 string with custom hash

Tags: php, encryption, hash, decode

I have an encrypted string and I wan't to know **" HOW IT IS ENCRYPTED ? "**
I know the flowing:

- The length of it is 34.
- It is based on IP address.
- It looks like `base64` or `Hex` string.
- I also know the custom hashing key.

An example:
**IP** : 192.56.57.53 
**Encrypted string :** 993f2e32e499124d0f1d9f89313bdeda42 
**Hashing key** : r2t6j805j35621y2a69140c4

> **NOTE :** the information in the example above are NOT REAL.

---

My question :
Is this possible to find out what's the function that generates this encrypted code from IP address by using the custom hashing?

Comment: base64 isn't hashing and doesn't use a key.

Comment: @tkausl the string looks like `base64` or `Hex`

Comment: Hashing and encryption aren't the same thing. A hash is one way while an encrypted string can be decrypted. Apples and oranges.